# What types of Exceptions can the XmlSerializer.Deserialize method throw?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, xml-serialization

For this method, `XmlSerializer.Deserialize`, what kinds of exception may be thrown? `XmlException`? `InvalidOperationException`? I did not find any exception description information from this method. My question is what kinds of exception could be thrown from this method?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dsh84875.aspx

I am using VSTS2008 + C# + .Net.

thanks in advance,
George

Comment: You haven't actually stated a problem...

Comment: My question is what kinds of exception could be thrown from this method?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Looks like primarily `InvalidOperationException`.

If you go through the documentation for each of the overloads, it will give you more details.  For example, see [`XmlSerializer.Deserialize Method (XmlReader)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tz8csy73.aspx)

The `InvalidOperationException` will contain more details about the specific error in its `InnerException` property.

Edit:

The [`XmlSerializer.Deserialize Method (XmlSerializationReader)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc221bxx.aspx) can throw a `NotImplementedException`, but it is an internal API and is not meant to be used by your code, so don't worry about it.

Edit 2:

This code:

```
var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
var deser = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(string));
deser.Deserialize(ms);
```

throws:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (0, 0). ---
System.Xml.XmlException: Root element is missing.
  at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
... <snip> ...
```

So it really looks like the framework will always throw an `InvalidOperationException`.

Really, unless you're worried about mistakenly catching exceptions like `ThreadAbortException`, you are probably safest catching *all* exceptions...

Edit 3:

Using [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/):  The `Deserialize(stream)` method reads the stream using an `XmlTextReader` and calls the [`XmlSerializer.Deserialize Method (XmlReader, String)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk9cbaf1.aspx).  That method throws an `InvalidOperationException` on error (according to the docs).

Edit 4:

`Deserialize(stream)` can also throw a `NullReferenceException` if `stream` is null, because it calls the [`XmlTextReader(Stream)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cssfs8c4.aspx) constructor.

Comment: But for this overload, there is no exception thrown. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dsh84875.aspx

Suppose we input a MemoryStream into this overload, and what kinds of exception may be thrown?

Comment: Thanks for your update, my major concern is about the overload which accept Stream (e.g. when we supply a MemoryStream), in MSDN I cannot find which kinds of exception may be thrown? Any ideas?

The overload I mentioned is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dsh84875.aspx

Comment: Thanks nader, I like your edit2 section, but where do you find the XmlException and InvalidOperationException? I did not find in MSDN, but how do you find it? :-)

So magic of you.

Comment: @George2:  That is just the stack trace from the exception (since an empty memory stream is not valid for deserialization) from my test code.  The XmlException will be the "InnerException" property on the "InvalidOperationException", which is what the Deserialize method will throw.  None of the methods are documented to throw XmlException -- they are all documented to throw InvalidOperationException.

Comment: @George2:  Have a look at my last update.  The overload you're looking at will throw an InvalidOperationException, since it doesn't do anything except call Deserialize(XmlReader,String)

Comment: Thanks, so I only need to catch NullReferenceException and InvalidOperationException?

Comment: @George2: As far as I can tell, yes those are the two types of exceptions that are thrown.

Comment: Thanks nader guru, my question is answered. :-)

Answer (score 7):

> *Exceptions from the XmlSerializer*
>
> Diagnosing the source of these problems can be tricky at first,
>   because the exceptions from the XmlSerializer do not seem to provide a
>   lot of information about the cause of their occurance; at least, they
>   do not provide the information in a spot where developers typically
>   would look.
>
> In most cases, Serialize, Deserialize and even the XmlSerializer
>   constructor throw a rather generic `System.InvalidOperationException`
>   when an error occurs. This exception type can occur in many places in
>   the .NET Framework; it is not specific to the XmlSerializer at all. To
>   make matters worse, the exception's Message property only yields very
>   generic information, as well.

This and other very handy tips about exceptions in the XmlSerializer can be found on the document [Troubleshooting Common Problems with the XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302290.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

George, because there is no exception contract in .NET, the best practice is to catch any specific exceptions that you may want to do special processing for, but to also have a catch-all exception handler that handles all failures appropriately.

I have implemented several XML serialization solutions using the built-in .NET serialization, and have in all cases just used a catch-all except block, which walks the innerexceptions of the caught exception, adding all error messages and exception class types to a string message. Doing it like that has always provided enough information to debug any serialization issues.

On a related note, what I normally do is to add a debug log level which logs the full xml to my application's log, so that I can inspect it to try and figure out what when wrong when debugging a serilization issue.

Comment: Thanks Joon, my idea is the same as yours, catch expected exception only and log for all exception information. But my question is, for this specific overload deserialization method http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dsh84875.aspx what kinds of exception may be thrown if deserialization fails?

Comment: @George: it doesn't matter. Whatever the answer is today, it may change tomorrow. You need to act ask though you don't know what exceptions may be thrown because, you don't know.